# Adding specific parameters to a datagrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

So i tried for some time to find a case like mine but couldnt really find anything helpfull.

My problem is that i have a datagrid where i need to have 2 columns with Assignmentnames and the creators of the assignments. Ive allready created the colums with their headers as you can see below.

```
   <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="257" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
   Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="479">

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Assignments" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Creator" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Furthermore i tried lining this code up as a test. For the final solution i will get the list of assignments from a database but im not at that point yet.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        assignment1 = new Assignment();
        assignment2 = new Assignment();
        assignments = new List<Assignment>();
        assignment1.AddBasicInformation("Engelsk A", "Hans Rueløkke", "Han gik en tur",      0);
        assignment1.AddBasicInformation("Historie B", "Lis Hansen", "Hvad hed den første mand på månen? ___.", 0);
        assignments.Add(assignment1);
        assignments.Add(assignment2);
        for(int i = 0; i < assignments.Count; i++)
        {
           dataGrid1.Items.Add(assignments);
        }
    }
```

As you can see the assignments contain 3 strings, an integer and furthermore they contain a couple of lists. The only information i want to be shown in the datagrid however is the first 2 strings. Anyone that can help me how to achieve that?

Editted the important part of my assignment class looks like this

```
    public class Assignment
{
    private string name;
    private string creator;
    private string assignmentText;
    private int type;
    private List<Answer> answerlist;

    public void AddBasicInformation(string aname, string acreator, string aassignmentText, int atype)
    {
        name = aname;
        creator = acreator;
        assignmentText = aassignmentText;
        type = atype;
        answerlist = new List<Answer>();
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public string GetCreator()
    {
        return creator;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the constructor, replace the for loop with:

```
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = assignments;
```

In the XAML, you can then declare the binding of the column (assuming the Assignment class has properties named Assignemnts and Creator):

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Assignments" Binding="{Binding Name} />
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Creator" Binding="{Binding Creator}" />
```

The binding of the ItemsSource is an anti-pattern in this example, but it will get you started.

For more info, see the [WPF DataGrid Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx).

**Edit**: In response to updated code samples by OP

All binding in WPF must be done with Properties. Update your Assignments Class to use Properties instead of fields:

```
public class Assignment
{
    Public string Name {get; set;}
    Public string Creator {get; set;}
    Public string AssignmentText {get; set;}

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, since i couldnt get it to work i guess i need to find out how to bind it to my assignmentclass i added it in my question now.

Comment: Take a look at the link to the WPF DataGrid I posted and read through that to get a better understanding of how `Binding` works in WPF.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer. Its late in the night in Denmark so ill wait till tommorow to read through that. Now it shows 3 rows where the first is filled out with the information from Assignment2 while the others are empty

Comment: Post back with follow up questions.